# AngularJS: Why can't I use my directive without using it inside a div-element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the AngularJS code below, why can't I use the rating directive like `<rating ... />` or `<rating ...></rating>`?
Reading the docs, it should be possible?

I've tried looking over the code, to see where it fails, but I can't find the reason. It works fine like

`<div rating rating-value="ratings.current" max="ratings.max" on-rating-selected="getSelectedRating(rating)"></div>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var starApp = angular.module('starApp', []);
    starApp.controller('starCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.rating = 0;
        $scope.ratings = {
            current: 5,
            max: 10
        };
        $scope.getSelectedRating = function(rating) {
            console.log(rating);
        }
    }]);


    starApp.directive('rating', function() {
        return { // directive definition object
            restrict: 'A', // directive will be used as an attribute
            template: '<ul class="rating">' + // directive expanded to template
                      '<li ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-class="star" ng-click="toggle($index)">' +
                      '\u2605' +
                      '</li>' +
                      '</ul>',
            scope: { // variables in scope of directive (passed in from HTML)
                ratingValue: '=', // expects an object from directive in HTML
                max: '=',
                onRatingSelected: '&'
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

                var updateStars = function() {
                    scope.stars = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < scope.max; i++) {
                        scope.stars.push({
                            filled: i < scope.ratingValue // filled is a boolean
                        });
                    }
                };


                scope.toggle = function(index) {
                    scope.ratingValue = index + 1;
                    scope.onRatingSelected({
                        rating: index + 1
                    });
                };

                // $watch() detect changes in scope variables ('ratingValue')
                scope.$watch('ratingValue', function(oldValue, newValue) {
                    if (newValue) {
                        updateStars();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="rating.css"/>
</head>
<body ng-app="starApp">
    <div ng-controller="starCtrl"> 
        <rating rating-value="ratings.current" max="ratings.max" on-rating-selected="getSelectedRating(rating)"></rating>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your directive is defined as "A" which means attribute.

```
(restrict: 'A', // directive will be used as an attribute)
```

You need to to restrice : 'E' for element, or 'AE' both.

Answer (score 2):

Change your restrict property to:

```
restrict: 'EA'
```

**E** means the directive can be a tag itself (`<rating></rating>`)

**A** means the directive can be an attribute to an HTML tag (`<div rating></div>`)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using restrict option to be `A` then your directive is restricted to attributes only, thus you cannot use element syntax for the directory. For that use `E`.

```
restrict: 'EA', //no need to worry for its order like 'AE' or 'EA'
```

The restrict option is typically set to:

```
'A' - only matches attribute name
'E' - only matches element name
'C' - only matches class name
```

These restrictions can all be combined as needed:

```
'AEC' - matches either attribute or element or class name
```

For more details: [view documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

---

There's also directive type `comment` and for that we can use `M` but its rarely used.